# iOS How can I display a downloaded PDF in an iOS App?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've written an iPhone App that downloads a PDF. I want to present this PDF to the user but not draw it in an UIView in my App itself. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Quartz APIs. `CGContextDrawPDFPage` and the related samples would be a nudge in the right direction.

`UIWebView` is another approach. As WTP noted below: *UIWebView automatically does pagination and allows the user to scroll, zoom and select content.*

`UIWebView` is the typical 'free' approach, but you may need Quartz APIs if you have special needs.

Comment: Note that UIWebView automatically does pagination and allows the user to scroll, zoom and select content.